# Force to reinstall from crash of office 2010 professional plus

Tags: installation, microsoft-office-2010, reinstall

Recently the macro and mail merge function of my copy of Office 2010 stopped working and that made me reinstall the system.

I have tried reinstall by choosing `Repair` but things remain erroneous like that.

I also tried to uninstall using Control Panel - Programs but that helpless either.

How do i force a reinstall of office from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You could remove the application, delete the `AppData` folders, and then reinstall. You could also use microsoft's removal tool.

There are some guides available on this microsoft knowledge base page: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290301